# dateCreated/ lastUpdated set to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in grails when using mariaDb galera cluster

Tags: mysql, datetime, grails, datasource, mariadb

I recently updated my grails application using **grails-2.2.4** from using  **mysql to mariadb** version **10.0.15-MariaDB-wsrep** with grails, I am using galera with it to support 3 node cluster. Everything was working fine with the mysql application, but after I switched to mariadb the dateCreated / lastUpdated field are not automatically getting the new timestamp but instead is set to **0000-00-00 00:00:00**. 
I've already tried

```
static mapping = {
    autoTimestamp true
}
```

in my domain setting and  globally set

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
autoTimestamp true 
}
```

but it still doesn't work

I also tried setting the default value to

```
 dateCreated=new Date();
```

Comment: What version of MySQL were you on before?  (There have been changes in TIMESTAMP defaults; grails may not be fixed yet -- just a wild guess.)

Comment: I've been using the application in different mysql version as the one in production and development is different. Currently deployed version of mysql in the server is 5.1.55-community

Comment: Talk with grails about their handling of dates.

Answer (score 4):

Try upgrading your mysql connector to latest version. In your buildconfig file

**dependencies**-
runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'

It should work!